# How can I create this imperfection?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, shaders, shader-nodes

[image: Imperfection On Floor]

I would be happy if someone could recreate this for me or give me tips on how to recreate this imperfection.

EDIT:
I've almost solved the problem, the only problem I'm stuck with right now is that I have downloaded [two overlays](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/smudges-large-001/1624) how can I apply them?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I've almost solved the problem, the only problem I'm stuck with right now is that I have downloaded two overlays ([LINK](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/smudges-large-001/1624))  how can I apply them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked B&W overlays](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/smudges-large-001/1624) can be used as a mask.

- You can use it to control roughness/metalness/transmission/color etc...
- Or even use a Mix Shader to combine different shaders

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you also upload the .blend file? I would appreciate it very much! :)

Comment: Hi :). Sure, here it is [on GDrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y27bCGjjix1WPNfAi9AJGkuHMMzaGGA1?usp=sharing)

Comment: How can I make it more wet? I have a closed room that emits light only from above, but not from the sides.

Comment: Hi :). 'Wetness' is mostly about reflections. Play with camera angle to get more reflections, but it won't be easy with only a flat top light ;)

Comment: Thanks, will try! :)